# How do I change the value of a java Path object?

Tags: java, path

Below, I am trying to change the value of the Path object **there** using the setSoundPath() method. I cannot find any documentation to say this is possible.

I am trying to create a class that will create a copy of a file at a specified path and put the copy in the specified folder. I need to be able to change the name of the path though, because I want to create the sound object with an initial placeholder file path.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

class Scratch {

    public static class Sound extends Object{

        private Path there;
        StringProperty tests = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "test", "");

        public Sound(){
            this.there = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\HNS1Lab.NETWORK\\Videos\\JuiceWRLD.mp3");
        }

        public void setSoundPath(String SoundPath) {
            this.tests.setValue(SoundPath);
            this.there = Paths.get(this.tests.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Sound test = new Sound();

            test.setSoundPath("C:\\Users\\HNS1Lab.NETWORK\\Music\\Meowing-cat-sound.mp3");
            test.copySound();
            System.out.println("Path: " + test.getSoundPath().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just create a new Path with that directory?

Comment: Because I want to know if it is possible to edit a currently existing path. I have already thought of the creating a new path option and have implemented it for now. I want to be able to change instead of create though. That way I can change the sound associated with the object on a whim if need be.

Comment: You are changing the value of the `there` field by calling `setSoundPath`. I don't understand the difference between doing this and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why have a `there` field at all?  It seems redundant when you have `tests`.  When you actually intend to play the sound, convert the string to a Path or File, but I see no reason to convert it before then.

Answer (score 2):

They are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object):

> Implementations of this interface are immutable and safe for use by
>   multiple concurrent threads.

(from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

You can create new Path objects that point to your path.

Comment: I don't want to create a new path, I want to edit the current one. I might be reading this wrong, but is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: The Path object can't be edited, it is immutable. Maybe I'm understanding your question not right? What's wrong with your code above?